# Laravel Eloquent Relation Two Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, eloquent-relationship

I have  two model. User, Images. How can I get all the users who has images and the image date is between start and end date. Date column name "date".

Comment: i want this and that is not acceptable without any code. show us your code what you have tried, what didn't work.

Comment: $users = User::whereHas('images', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')]);
        })->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Eloquent whereHas().
So the code should look like:

```
$users= User::whereHas('images', function($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
     return $query->where([
       ['date', > , $start_date],
       ['date', < , $end_sate],
     ]);
})->get();
```

Document: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence
Do not forget to format the date to however you want. Considering using whereDate()/whereBetween() is advised. Just play around till you get it right.

Comment: It's getting all the images. But If I run the same condition with single Model it works. But with two model it's not working.

Comment: @Mehadi Can you elaborate your problem futher? I don't quite get it. If it's getting all the images, try replaceing `where()` with `whereBetween('date', [ $start_date, $end_date])`. And of cource the script above only works for one mode instance. If you want to work with more than one model instance, put it insdie a foreach loop

Comment: I need it work with two Model. 
User and Images 
User have Images. 
-- 
I want to run a query where I can get all users with images and the images.date should be between date_start and date_end 
--- 
Currently I have written this code but it's not filtering the dates. 

$users = User::whereHas('images', function (Builder $query) { $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')]); })->get();

Answer (score 0):

in **controller** class write a query to fetch all user with who has images and date is between the start and end date

```
  $from = date('2018-01-01');
  $to = date('2018-05-02');

     $users= DB::table('users')
            ->join('images', 'users.is', '=', 'images.user_id')
            ->select('users.*')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$from , $to])
            ->distinct('users.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Is there any way to  do it without DB query? 
Can we do it with model?